# WebBrowser.Print() wait until complete. .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printing, browser

I am using a WebBrowser control in VB.NET and calling the Print() method.  I am printing out using a PDF printer and when Print() is called it is not immediately kicked off (it waits until it has completed running code for the entire Sub or block.

I need to make sure the file I am printing too is complete and continue process with this file, therefore, I would like to print on demand and get some status of when the operation is complete.  I have tried usign printDocument and process without luck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Check out the `PrintTemplateTeardown` event of the underlying unmanaged WebBrowser object. Sometimes that event gets fired multiple times but hopefully this will point you in the right direction. You need to add a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls`.

```
Private Sub Print()
    AddHandler DirectCast(WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance, SHDocVw.WebBrowser).PrintTemplateTeardown, AddressOf PrintDone
    WebBrowser1.Print()
End Sub
Private Sub PrintDone(ByVal obj As Object)
    Trace.WriteLine("printed")
    RemoveHandler DirectCast(WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance, SHDocVw.WebBrowser).PrintTemplateTeardown, AddressOf PrintDone
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to get a handle on your 'printjobscollection' for your default printer and ensure that the jobcount = 0

like this in vb.net:

```
    Dim intprint As Integer = Nothing

    retry2:
    intprint = GetPrintJobsCollection(printerinuse)
    If Not intprint = 0 Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        GoTo retry2
    End If
    'do what you want to do after print completes here
```